# Save changes in Kendo Grid without closing the popup window, but update the model

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

In the editor template of the Kendo Grid, I'd like to save changes when certain event has been triggered. I'd like to keep the window open, so user can continue to update other fields. I save the changed by the following codes in the editor template:

```
function innerGridEditEvent(e) {
    var model = e.model;
    if (!model.isNew)
        return;
    var Id = parseInt($("#Id").val(), 10);
    if (!Id) {
        var masterGrid = $("#masterGrid").data('kendoGrid');
        masterGrid.saveChanges();
    }
}
```

And I keep the popup window open by using this function on `SaveChanges` event of the main Grid.

```
function masterSaveChanges(e) {
        var grid = e.sender;
        grid.bind("dataBinding", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        })
}
```

It works fine, but I need to have the newly created `Id`. In other words I want an updated model.

If it matters or you want to suggest any workarounds, inside the editor template, I have another grid and I'd like to set the `read` and `create` data of that Grid.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid< >()
.Name("InnerGrid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    ....
})
.ToolBar(toolbar =>
{
    toolbar.Create();
})
.DataSource(ds => ds
    .Ajax()
    ....
    .Read(r => r.Action(" ", " ").Data("getId"))
    .Create(c => c.Action(" ", " ").Data("getId"))
)
.Events(e => e.Edit("innerGridEditEvent"))
)
```

I'm keeping the required Id as a hidden field, and the `getId` event returns it.

```
function getHeadId(e) {
    var id = $("#Id").val();
    return { Id: id };
}

....
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
```

Comment: I think I'm missing something here. Why do you want to update the model just to update an id.  Ain't the id a field already?

Comment: ID is a field, but it's 0, until I insert the record and get the new ID. I don't want to update the models, I want to insert them. If Id is already set, I don't need any other thing to do.

Comment: As a part of this question: how can I get the sender grid from the popup window? I want to improve the `innerGridEditEvent` function. It's currently using hard-coded value.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I worked around this with having a global variable and setting its value on `dataBinding`. So the `SaveChanges` handler of the master grid is:

```
function masterGridSaveChanges(e) {
    var grid = e.sender;
    grid.bind("dataBinding", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        setId(e.items[0].LiIdH);
    })
}
```

The inserted items is always the first one in `items`, at least I hope so! They [say](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-dataBinding) it has to have `e.index` too, but mine was always `undefined`.

In this case instead of a global `var`, I have created a setter inside the editor template.

```
function setHeadId(value) {
    $("#Id").val(value);
}
```

And the rest of the app remains untouched.